# gdb: stop the program when the variable changes

Tags: variable, gdb

So I was wondering how to stop gdb every time my variable (test_v) changes

I know

```
 watch test_v
```

Do I do

```
 watch test_v
 stop
```

To stop the program every time the variable test_v changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `stop` to make the program stop when the variable changes. Just `watch test_v` is enough.

`stop` command is not for stopping the program, but only meant to be hooked so you can execute some commands automatically when the program stops. Example usage from the gdb manual:

```
define hook-stop
handle SIGALRM nopass
end

define hook-run
handle SIGALRM pass
end

define hook-continue
handle SIGALRM pass
end
```